# grocery cart on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create add-to-cart app.
Want to click each item and add it to cart.
But firstly I need to click button 'add to cart' and increase its value with every click.
As I added ng-repeat, I don't know how to write a function that will be responsible for adding separate item.

```
angular.module('TransactionApp', [])
.controller('TransactionsCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.title = 'Online-store';

   $scope.itemsArray = [
    {  price: 50, name: "Whey protein", img: 'img/item-1.png', quantity: 0},
    {  price: 60, name: "Protein bar", img: 'img/item-2.png', quantity: 0  },
    {  price: 35, name: "BCAA", img: 'img/item-3.png', quantity: 0  },
    {  price: 50, name: "Whey protein", img: 'img/item-1.png', quantity: 0  },
    {  price: 60, name: "Protein bar", img: 'img/item-2.png', quantity: 0  },
    {  price: 80, name: "BCAA", img: 'img/item-3.png', quantity: 0  }

   ];

   // $scope.count = 0;
   $scope.addTo = function(){

   }

});
```

here is html:

```
    <h2 class="title">{{title}} <i class="em em-shopping_bags"></i></h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-6">
         <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" ng-repeat='item in itemsArray'>
      <img class="card-img-top" ng-src={{item.img}} alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.name}}</p>
        <p class="price">{{ item.price | currency }}</p>
        <a href="#"  class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="addTo()"><i class="em em-shopping_trolley"></i>  Add to cart <span class="number">{{ item.quantity }}</span></a>

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In addTo method you need to add items to cart.

Comment: @VijayRaheja, I understand but how?

Comment: You are talking about AngularJS (ng-repeat), do you? you tagged the question with "Angular" (would be ngFor then).

Comment: Items must have unique Id, which you need to pass to addTo() method in ng-click. Inside addTo take items from ItemsArray and add to cart.

Comment: ngrepeat has a variable $index in it. With that you can catch the corresponding item in your array. Take a look at "https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat"

Comment: You can do like that call function addToCart(item);
In controller $scope.addToCart = function(item){cart.push(item);}

Its a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the item to controller with `addTo(item)`:

```
<a href="#"  class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="addTo(item)">
  <i class="em em-shopping_trolley"></i>
  Add to cart
  <span class="number">{{ item.quantity }}</span>
</a>
```

after your `addTo` accepts a parameter:

```
$scope.addTo = function(item){ // 'item' is a reference to an element in itemsArray
  item.quantity++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe each of your item in view has its own `Add to Cart` Button against it and I also believe you want to increase the `quantity` property of each of the item each time a user clicks the button against that item.

For that all you have to do is pass the item to `addTo()` method like :-

```
<a href="#"  class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="addTo(item)"><i class="em em-shopping_trolley"></i>  Add to cart <span class="number">{{ item.quantity }}</span></a>
```

and modify the method definition in `controller`

```
$scope.addTo = function(var item){
    item.quantity++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It hepled me much !